# How can I animate the UIButton highlight property to extend the time that it stays highlighted?

Tags: animation, uibutton, highlight

Attempting to programmatically highlight a UIButton configured with "Shows Touches On Highlight," found that the following code does not animate properly (the duration has no effect; the highlight just flashes):

```
button.highlighted = YES;
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                 animations:^{ button.highlighted = NO; }
 ];
```

Also attempted, with similar (just a flash) results:

```
button.highlighted = YES;
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                 animations:^{}
                 completion:^(BOOL finish){ button.highlighted = NO; }
 ];
```

What is the best way to turn the button highlight on programmatically, and then turn it off after some duration?

Answer (score 0):

The following code produced the desired result:

```
button.highlighted = YES;
[self performBlock:^{ button.highlighted = NO; } afterDelay:3.0];
```

NOTE: 3.0 seconds used for illustration / consistency only; 0.3 seconds is actually the visual effect we were seeking.